# Install Danginx and REMOTE_ADDR shows server ip

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, centos, ip

I installed Danginx and when REMOTE_ADDR shows server ip instead of user ip.
I tryed use mod_remoteip (I have apache 2.4) but its shows me error.

```
apxs -cia mod_remoteip.c
/var/www/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread -I/usr/include/apache  -I/usr/includ/apache   -I/usr/include/apache   -c -o mod_remoteip.lo mod_remoteip.c && touch mod_remoteip.slo
gcc: mod_remoteip.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

After that I tryed to download this module and compile it, and than when I tryed enable httpd service it told me that I try enable build-in module.

What can I do for show real IP of users?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using both Nginx and Apache?

Comment: I use nginx as proxy server for up speed of website loadings.